# How can I change the sensitivity of Dismiss Behaviour of BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. But even the slightest downward swipe dismisses the Dialog. 
I do not want to make it static and remove the swipe down to dismiss behaviour. I want to be able to change the sensitivity, if the swipe is `x` pixels downwards, then dismiss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `BottomSheetBehavior`

this will get the behavior for your BottomSheetDialogFragment view

```
var mBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = BottomSheetBehavior.from([your view reference])
```

then you can setup like this

```kotlin
val dismissOffset: Float = [-1..0] // 0 is the starting position. -1 is hidden. -0.5 is middle

var offset: Float? = null

mBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING) {
                    if (offset!! > dismissOffset) {
                        mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)
                    } else {
                        mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                offset = slideOffset
            }
        })
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as possible and get back to you, thank you

Comment: Could you tell me, where i should do this?

Comment: if you are using your own custom BottomSheetDialogFragment, you can put this in the place you init the fragment, `onCreateDialog` or `onViewCreated`. The main point is to get your view's reference and use that reference to get the view's behavior.

Comment: Does this work? When I run set the state to `STATE_EXPANDED`, it only seems to work initially. It expands, but dismisses right afterwards. It only works when you slowly drag and release the touch, not when you're actually swiping.

Comment: @funct7 I have the same problem, did you found any solution?

Comment: @DanieleSoprani I ended up implementing my own subclass of `BottomSheetBehavior`. I [raised an issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2520) and you can see the most relevant parts of the implementation there. It uses a lot of reflection which is not shown in the code snippet.

Comment: Your implementation seems interesting, you should do a pull request. I just opened a new issue https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2993

Answer (score 0):

The answer of ChiChung Luk almost acceptable, but I have tried it with `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1` library and it didn't work as expected. First of all `slideOffset` changes from 1 to -1, and not from 0 to -1. The second issue was that even when we set `mBehavior.setState(STATE_EXPANDED)` in `onStateChanged`, the system any way sets the state to `STATE_HIDDEN` after the bottom sheet is expanded, from `onStopNestedScroll > startSettlingAnimation`. So there should be a flag that disallow hide before bottom sheet is not expanded.
Solution:

```
bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

    val dismissOffset: Float = -0.2f // when less value then wider should be swipe gesture to dismiss

    private var currOffset: Float = 1f // from 1 to -1

    private var dismissAllowed: Boolean = true

    override fun onStateChanged(
        bottomSheet: View, @BottomSheetBehavior.State newState: Int
    ) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING) {
            if (currOffset > dismissOffset) {
                dismissAllowed = false
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            } else {
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
            }
        } else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            dismissAllowed = true
        } else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            if (dismissAllowed) {
                dialog.cancel()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        currOffset = slideOffset
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for setting me in the right direction. I ended up overriding the class itself, since the `BottomSheetBehavior` implementation was wrong and it was no longer a problem with the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that like me, you had a `NestedScrollView` in your bottom sheet (this is the only thing that caused the behavior you described to happen for me).

My solution was as follows:

```
/** Convenience function to fix https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1055 */
private fun NestedScrollView.fixNestedScrolling(dialog: BottomSheetDialog) {
    fun updateScrollView(scrollY: Int) {
        val wasNestedScrollingEnabled = isNestedScrollingEnabled
        isNestedScrollingEnabled = scrollY > 0
        if (wasNestedScrollingEnabled != isNestedScrollingEnabled) {
            // If property has changed, we need to requestLayout for it to apply to swipe gestures.
            dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)?.requestLayout()
        }
    }

    setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, scrollY, _, _ -> updateScrollView(scrollY) }

    // Fire off initial update
    updateScrollView(0)
}
```

The `NestedScrollView` still works correctly, and once scrollY == 0 (i.e. we're at the top), nested scrolling is disabled so the `BottomSheetBehavior` uses the (much more natural) calculations that it usually does before initiating a dismiss.